# Debian & Bind - Forwarding to external DNS not working

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind

I am a newbie in configuring DNS servers, I need your help...

I have one debian 10 with webmin + bind 9.11 installed.
I got a local domain which is working fine.

From one host on my LAN, I can resolve internal hostnames :

```
dig @myinternalDNS host1.local.lan +show

<@IP-host1>
```

but when I try to resolve Internet names, I got no response :

```
dig @myinternalDNS www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4 <<>> @<@IP-myinternalDNS> www.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 16965
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 2c052e0915fc346f652fbf325e8c51c9a65c4fbb5204c698 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: <@IP-myinternalDNS>#53(<@IP-myinternalDNS>)
;; WHEN: mar. avr. 07 12:11:22     2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 71
```

My configuration is pretty simple :

```
acl allowed {
        X.Y.Z.0/24;
        };

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { localhost; allowed; };
        listen-on port 53 { localhost; <@IP-myinternalDNS>; };
        allow-query {
                localhost;
                allowed;
                };
        allow-transfer {
                localhost;
                allowed;
                };

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
};

zone "local.lan" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/local.lan.hosts";
        };
zone "Z.Y.X.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/Z.Y.X.rev";
        };
```

NB: I replaced my real IP network with X.Y.Z

And from my DNS, I can resolve Internet names.

Why this is not working ?
Could you help me please ?

**EDIT 1:**

I captured packets on my outgoing router, and the DNS requests are going to public DNS servers and are responding.

There is no network difference between a dig @8.8.8.8 and requesting my server.
When my server requests the public DNS, the packet is gone and comes back but the DNS answer is empty, whereas with a dig @8.8.8.8 directly from my server, I have a successfully DNS answer.

Very strange, I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have set up both a caching and forwarding DNS server, so I'd say to either set it up like this for a recursive server:

```
acl allowed {
        X.Y.Z.0/24;
        };

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-recursion { localhost; allowed; };
        listen-on port 53 { localhost; <@IP-myinternalDNS>; };
        allow-query {
                localhost;
                allowed;
                };
        allow-transfer {
                localhost;
                allowed;
                };

        };
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
};
```

Or like this for a forwarding server:

```
acl allowed {
        X.Y.Z.0/24;
        };

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        listen-on port 53 { localhost; <@IP-myinternalDNS>; };
        allow-query {
                localhost;
                allowed;
                };
        allow-transfer {
                localhost;
                allowed;
                };

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
        };
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
};
```

Also remember to check your config before restarting bind:

```
sudo named-checkconf
```

Comment: Hey Stuggi, thanks for your help.
I tried both solutions, but in each case the issue is still the same...

Which logs can I send you to troubleshoot more further ?

Comment: Are you certain that the server can resolve names in general? Try running dig against 8.8.8.8 for example.

Comment: Sure, he can...

Comment: Okay, your edit made the problem even more confusing :) Have a look at this how to configure BIND logging, it's a bit of a can of worms https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01526